# Why div is not taking full height on mobile divice

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 `div` 1 `header`, `Sidebar` and `main content`. I have used `flexbox`. `.main` has `100vh` `height` and `.sidebar` has `100px` `height` and `.main-content` has  `100%` `height`. But it is viewed on mobile then empty space is shown between `sidebar` and `main-content`.

```css
.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-content{
  width: 80%;}
  
  .sidebar {
    width: 20%
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Header</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    main-content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this may not be related to your issue, but `sidebar` is a class, so you need a period before it `.` (in the media-query)

Comment: You say `sideBar` has `100px` set and you ask why in mobile it doesn't have `100%` height ? or you meant `header` ?

Comment: what do you mean by ' space'  and mobile ? below which screen size ?

Comment: @Mihai T Run the snippet. you will understand

Comment: Just remove "min-height: 100vh;" from the .main and your problem will be solved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `flex-direction: column` to `main`. And use `flex-grow: 1` to main-content so it covers the remaining space ( if you want that )

The default property value is `row`. So main and sidebar are side by side and equal in height which is equal to the height of their container( default flex behavior )

```css
.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;

}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow:1;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .main-content{
  width: 80%;}
 
  .sidebar {
    width: 20%
  }
  .main {
    flex-direction:row;
 }
}
```

```html
<div>Header</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    main-content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.. but on desktop I want both block side by side and on mobile they should show 1 below the other

Comment: well, isn't that what's happening ?

Comment: nope.. even on desktop also they are showing below each other

Comment: just add `  .main {
    flex-direction:row;
 } ` in the media query. I updated it now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-content,
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
  }
}`

Comment: Please edit your answer so you use a code snippet and a short explanation. Otherwise this can be considered a low quality answer and get downvoted. You can even click on `copy snippet to answer` from the question.

Answer (score 0):

For a `height` setting with a percentage value ( as in `.sidebar` and `.main-content`) the parent element of these (`.main`) needs to have a `height` setting defined, as a reference for their percentage value. `min-height` isn't sufficient in this case.

So, in `.main`, you could change `min-height: 100vh` to `height: 100vh` and add `overflow-y: visible` to allow it to get larger.

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y:visible;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-content{
  width: 80%;}
  
  .sidebar {
    width: 20%
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Header</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    main-content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "min-height: 100vh;" from the .main and your problem will be solved! :)